# Как при наведение на дочерний компонент изменить css у родительского компонента React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Есть несколько вложенных функциональных компонентов друг в друга.

```
<Component 1>
  <Component 2>
    <Component 3>
      <Component 4 />
    </Component 3>
  </Component 2>
</Component 1>
```

У компонента 1 есть подсветка при наведение (hover). Как сделать так, чтобы при наведение на вложенный компонент 4 снималось выделение у всего компонента 1 ?

Comment: Вынесите стили в глобальный файл

Comment: Во Vue.js события можно использовать `$emit()`, в React наверняка тоже такое должно быть.

Comment: К сожалению используем material ui + styled-components, отдельно какой-то css сделать весьма трудно. По другому решил задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем привет!
Решил задачу следующим образом: через передачу коллбэка от родителя к дочернему элементу.

у Родителя, где будем менять делаем примерно следующее:

```
const [background, setBackground] = useState(" ");
```

Далее, используем возможность встроенных стилей в реакте:

```
style={{backgroundColor: background}}
```

И в дочерний передаем пропом:

```
changeBackground={background => setBackground(background)}
```

Во все промежуточные компоненты указываем:

```
changeBackground={changeBackground}
```

В нижний дочерний:

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
style={{backgroundColor:`${isHovered ? changeBackground('white') : changeBackground(COLOR.STEEL_TRANSPARENT)}`}}
```